# Separate and write unique files from delimited text

Tags: python-3.x, text, split

I am following [this tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U5Y-tdfY3k) to separate and write out a delimited text file, but only get one file on output. Is this a python2 -> 3 issue? Help please.

```
filename = ('file path')

with open(filename) as Input:
    op = ''
    start = 0
    count = 1
    for x in Input.read().split("\n"):
        if (x == 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'):
            if (start == 1):
                with open(str(count) + '.txt', 'w') as Output:
                    Output.write(op)
                    Output.close()
                    op = ''
                    count = + 1
            else:
                start = 1
    Input.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have allways `count = 1`.

Change this line:

```
count = + 1
```

to

```
count += 1
```